# Show that $V^* \neq \{0\}$ if $V \neq \{0\}$ normed space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Suppose $V$ be a non zero normed space( possibly infinite dimensional). Can we prove that $V^*$ the space of continuous linear functional is non zero without using Hahn Banach theorem?

Comment: This is a somewhat vague question. Do you mean to avoid using axiom of choice altogether? If so, you should add the appropriate tag.

Comment: @tomasz: Is it obvious assuming axiom of choice?

Comment: What I mean is that Hahn-Banach can be considered a weak form of axiom of choice (it may not be true without choice). If you do allow choice, you can probably just prove a special case of Hahn-Banach.

Comment: @tomasz: On page $15$ of https://www.imsc.res.in/~sunder/fa.pdf notes it is said that the reader should spend a little time thinking about why $V^* \neq \{0\}$ if $V \neq \{0\}$ normed space.Since it was not clear to me thats why i asked the question.

Comment: What makes you think "because of Hahn-Banach theorem" is not an acceptable answer?

Comment: @tomasz: Because the above remark is made before the statement of the theorem!

Comment: In that case, I think the intention is to show the reader that even this kind of "obvious" fact is not that obvious at all, and the easiest way to obtain it is via the Hahn-Banach theorem. I doubt the author meant for you to find an argument which would circumvent it entirely. Why don't you ask him directly?

Comment: @tomasz: I personally don't know the author,i am reading  notes which i found by google search!

Answer (score 6):

One possible answer: NO.  By that I mean:

> $V^* \ne \{0\}$ cannot be proved in ZF.

So some consequence of the Axiom of Choice (such as the Hahn-Banach theorem) is required.  My favorite example for this is the Banach space

$$
 V = l^\infty / c_0
$$
Exhibiting an element of this $V^*$ is the same as exhibiting a functional on $l^\infty$ that does not come from an element of $l^1$

Comment: On page $15$ of https://www.imsc.res.in/~sunder/fa.pdf notes it is said that the reader should spend a little time thinking about why $V^* \neq \{0\}$ if $V \neq \{0\}$ normed space.Since it was not clear to me thats why i asked the question.

Comment: If one looks at the algebraic dual instead of the continuous one, is it still so that $V^*\neq0$ needs the axiom of choice?

Comment: @s.harp ...  Of course.  Without AC, perhaps every linear functional on a Banach space is automatically continuous.  Your question ($V^* \ne 0$ for every vector space $V \ne 0$) is probably in the Rubin list of equivalents/consequences of AC.